# Wordpress is_home = true

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using thumbnail excerpts for my wordpress blog.
This has to the option to set thumbnails on archives, homepage and search.

I built an extra template page to only show news as my main homepage shows the latest events.

Is there any way you can set another variable that it makes your template page look as is_home(), this way it'll give me the thumbnails as well.

Thanks

Comment: better fit to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Svisstack naah. This is clearly a programming question. If anything, it should go on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this in your template.

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->is_home = true;
```